# How to handle an exception that is thrown in the RestControllerAdvice?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class InotApiControllerAdvice {

...

@ExceptionHandler(UpdateAssetAuthenticationException.class)
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<JobResponse>> handleUpdateAssetAuthenticationException(UpdateAssetAuthenticationException e) {   
        if(e.getNbRetry() >= MAX_RETRIES) {
            return Mono.error(new Exception("Authentication Exception in UpdateAsset for id "+e.getId()+" - name "+e.getName()+" - value "+e.getValue()));
        }
        LOG.info("Authentication Exception in UpdateAsset for id {} - name {} - value {}... Retrying with new token", e.getId(), e.getName(), e.getValue());
        Mono<String> refreshToken = inotApiService.doRefreshToken();
        if(refreshToken != null) {
            return refreshToken.doOnSuccess(token -> {
                inotApiService.setAccessToken(token);                   
            }).then(inotApiService.createAsset(e.getName(), e.getValue(), e.getNbRetry() + 1))
              .then(inotApiService.startJob(e.getName()))
              .flatMap(response -> just(ResponseEntity.ok(response)));                  
        }
        return Mono.error(new Exception("No valid authentication method found in UpdateAsset for id "+e.getId()+" - name "+e.getName()+" - value "+e.getValue()));
    }

}
```

There is an exception that might get thrown when calling **inotApiService.startJob** and it is handled as follows :

```
    @ExceptionHandler(InotApiException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleInotApiException(InotApiException iae) {     
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .body(new ErrorResponse(iae.getMessage()));
    }
```

The problem is that when the exception is thrown, this handler method is not called and I get a 500 response by the **AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler**

Any ideas on how we could handle this exception even if it is thrown in the **@RestControllerAdvice** class ?

Comment: *There is an exception that might get thrown when calling inotApiService.startJob and it is handled as follows :* Handled where? In the same ControllerAdvice?

Comment: Regardless of whether you can make this work the logic in handler 1 would  seem to  me to better suited to the service layer. I would expect MVC exception handlers to be concerned with generating a suitable response to the client, nothing more.

Comment: @AlanHay Yes, in the same controllerAdvice. And it's WebFlux not MVC. Thank you

Comment: You should not throw exceptions, you should propagate errors down the event chain. You have multiple things you should take care of. You are nullchecking if you even returned a mono? You either return a mono.error or a mono.empty dont return NULL. You chain a lot of then-cllas why not just list them all in doOnSuccess. Your ”job” should run in its own Scheduler so it doesnt hog one of the threads in the reactive forkjointhreadpool. If not taken care of you might get crazy bad performance.